# AWS Lambda: Is it secure to store data on AWS Lambda local Disk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have following basic security related questions regarding AWS Lambda service:

1. Where does AWS Lambda store data if for example I try to store data on local disk?
2. Is is possible to encrypt the data on Lambda?

Thanks

Answer (score 17):

One important sidenote to the /tmp of Lambda functions is that the Lambda function containers are re-used and scratch space is **not always** erased. If an invocation uses a container that was spun up because of a previous invocation (this happens if you execute a few Lambda function in quick succession), the scratch space is shared.

This screwed up a functionality for me once.

Comment: To clarify, it's not always erased for subsequent invocations **of your function**.  You aren't going to find someone else's data there.

Comment: @Luc Hendriks how can I cleanup the tmp folder ?

Comment: You can just remove the files. If you use node js, you can do `fs.readdir` to get all files in the tmp folder, and then for each file do a `fs.unlink` for example. You can also spawn a child process and do for example this (it should work as a oneliner but you want to split the requires and make it async): `require('child_process').execSync('rm -rf /tmp')`

Answer (score 6):

I store temporary data in my lambda function, never had any issue.

- Store your data in /tmp, you may not have access to other dirs
- The temporary data - as the name indicates - is available only for that invocation of lambda
- If the data is sensitive, encrypt it (if the encryption libraries are not provided by default for that language, make sure you package the library)

Answer (score 3):

Files stored on Lambda's local volumes should be for temporary short-term storage only and should not be expected to persist beyond the lifetime of your single Lambda function invocation.

If you need to store data long-term, use a database like DynamoDB or use Amazon S3.

If you must store data on the local volume, you can encrypt it, but you must do it yourself. Also, note that the next time the function is called, the data most likely will be gone.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response,

Yes it is fine if data is deleted on next function call, since it is temporary.

Do we know where does the local disk of Lambda lives, under S3 etc?

Comment: Most likely it's an EBS volume, but it may be EC2 instance-store (ie. local hard drive to the EC2 instance). It will not be S3.

Answer (score 2):

If you by "secure" asks who will have access to data then the answer is anyone that can call the lambda. If you by "secure" also wonder if it is durable storage, then the answer is no. Lambda functions only have access to an ephemeral `/tmp` folder. There is no guarantee that the two consecutive calls to the same lambda function will be executed on the same physical machine. However, if the function is called twice within a short period of time, it could be executed on the very same machine and then a file that was saved by the first call may be available to the second call. If you choose to use this temporary file storage you should also be aware that there are some [limitations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) of how much data that can be stored.

Comment: Thanks for the information. So If I understand correctly, any other Lambda can view the /tmp directory? this feels odd since anyone can delete or read the data (if that is the case). Let me ask another question. How does Lambda use the RAM, for example if I allocate 1024 RAM (through web UI) and on average launch 5-7 Lambda functions in 1-10 seconds (S3 will launch Lambda functions), is this RAM divided among all Lambda functions, or every single Lambda function will have 1024 RAM allocated?

Comment: @obaid No, "Each Lambda function receives 500MB of non-persistent disk space _in its own_ /tmp directory." (emphasis mine, copied from [Lambda FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/)). 

Each request to a Lambda function will have its own memory allocation, otherwise it would not scale out. The alternative (a fixed memory budget for all requests to a specific Lambda) does not make sense. Such a solution would imply that each request would get less and less memory when the traffic increase up to a point when it would inevitably throw an out of memory exception.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda store data in lambdas `\tmp` folder.

and it is not secure the store data on lambda

 reason is  when lambda function completes its execution it will delete all the data which is in the `\tmp` folder 

**solution** before terminating the lambda function or completion of the script move data from `\tmp` folder `aws  s3 bucket`.