# Storing secrets in AWS Lambda package

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kms

I'm currently storing a Google Cloud private key file in my Lambda. Its excluded from source control and packaged in to the final lambda zip file before its uploaded to AWS.

Is this secure?

I understand that storing secrets in the environment variables is a bad idea for various reasons (appearing in logs, etc) but I don't currently know if the way I'm doing it is bad (gaps in my knowledge).

I know KMS exists for encrypting secrets but it seems like a lot more work to use it and having to make a request to decrypt the file every time my lambda is called (or every time my lambda gets a new execution context) seems inefficient.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35182549/aws-lambda-is-it-secure-to-store-data-on-aws-lambda-local-disk

Answer (score 1):

**Parameter store** can be used to store **passwords/secret text** provided by AWS Service: **Systems Manager**.

Below is Example :

[image]

Access to these passwords can be restricted by the IAM Policies following [Guide to IAM policies for Parameter store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-paramstore-access.html)

A Lambda can be attached role via which you can query for passwords/secret text. No File decryption needed. Just 1/2 API Calls.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. I know KMS and parameter store exist (parameter store sits on top of KMS I believe). What security/process/efficiency benefit do they give me over my current method.

Comment: Michael,  
1. Security - Access via IAM policies to restrict the access to the secrets to the requried user 
2. Process - Only the desired people can do the change in secret
3. Efficiency: Currently as per your question, you decrypt the file. Now its just API Calls to get he password. You can load on run time.

Comment: Access to my lambda package is also restricted and I'm not sure there is a way to download an uploaded package. Only people with access to lambda can change the secret. I don't decrypt the file at the moment, its a json file that is packaged with the lambda executable. API call will be slower.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to download the Lambda Package [ Read only access can also do as its ReadOnly call ]. Yes API Call will be a little slow but it give flexibility in changing secret when needed else you have to upload the complete package.

Comment: The user would require some kind of administrative access to my AWS account though. If they've got that, its the least of my worries. Releasing a new version of my lambda is accomplished in 1 command that takes ~15 seconds to run. I'm ok with that!

Comment: @MichaelBaldry - AWS Lambda service has now Option to `encrypt` environment variables using the AWS KMS. I guess that will resolve your problem now.