# How secure is using the /tmp directory in an AWS lambda?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've been looking at implementing the `aws_encryption_sdk` in a lambda to deal with encrypted files that are uploaded into a s3 bucket.

I have been able to get it to work by downloading the file into the `/tmp` directory (giving the file a unique name), decrypting the file in the same directory and then uploading the decrypted file back into s3.  I am also deleting the files in the system after the operation has completed, but before exiting the lambda

While using the file system is common use case, I have concerns around the use of the `/tmp` directory and its security.

Can anyone advise whether I should be concerned?  How exclusive is the file system when you fire up Lambdas?

Thanks

Comment: Similar question with answers is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35182549/aws-lambda-is-it-secure-to-store-data-on-aws-lambda-local-disk). Also lambda [secirty page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/security-dataprotection.html#security-privacy-intransit) only states that AWS secures env variables and endpoints are https. /tmp is not mentioned at all. Thus I wouldn't make any assumptions about security of /tmp storage if this is of vital importance.

Comment: It's not visible to other Lambdas in your account or to other AWS accounts, obviously. It might be visible to a (warm) second invocation of your same Lambda function, if the first invocation crashed before it could delete the file. It's also possible, I suppose, that your second invocation could use `lsof` or equivalent to attempt to undelete the file, but that's within your control. Ideally, you should not persist this file to /tmp but instead stream it into the Lambda function, decrypt in memory, and then stream it back out of the Lambda function to S3. And wipe the Lambda's global data.

Comment: @Marcin, I appreciate the links.
jarmod, Thank you for the run down.  Based on what I have read since posting this, I think that streaming is going to be the "belts and braces" approach to the solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is somewhat safe to use `/tmp` in Lambda, meaning that your `/tmp` folder will not be shared with other AWS clients. At the same time:

1. There is no evidence that any disk space allocated for `/tmp` is actually wiped. Since AWS Lambda doesn't provide low-level block access to the underlying disk, it's safe enough, but not military-grade. RAM memory **is** wiped:

> Lambda scrubs the memory before assigning it
>   to an execution environment, which effectively guards against memory sharing between
>   functions that belong to the same account and different customer accounts.

So for high-security applications, you might consider keeping your decrypted content in memory.

2. Keep in mind that `/tmp` is not recreated/cleared on each Lambda invocation. Quite the opposite, if your Lambda runs several times in a short period of time the invocations will run in the same context and `/tmp` content will be preserved. That's a [feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-context.html), not a bug.

> After a Lambda function is executed, AWS Lambda maintains the execution context for some time in anticipation of another Lambda function invocation.
>
> Each execution context provides 512 MB of additional disk space in the /tmp directory. The directory content remains when the execution context is frozen, providing transient cache that can be used for multiple invocations. You can add extra code to check if the cache has the data that you stored.

If you really care about the security aspect of Lambda, I suggest you read [Security Overview of AWS Lambda: An In-Depth Look at Lambda Security](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Overview-AWS-Lambda-Security.pdf) whitepaper.